# Неизвестный синтаксис в шаблоне сайта. Как определить шаблонизатор?

Tags: cms

Развернул бэкап сайта, а там в шаблоне непонятный синтаксис. Что за шаблонизатор используется? Пример кода:

```
<head>
    <:#meta_tags/>
    <:lib_load(
        'kickstart.layout'   
        , 'kickstart.buttons'
        , 'kickstart.grid'   
        , 'kickstart.tiptip' 
        , 'icms.styles'      
        , 'font-awesome'     
        , 'icms.adaptive'
        , 'jquery.jcarousellite'
    )/>

    <:lib_flush("css")/>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <:css(['/tpl/ie6.css'])/>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <:css(['/tpl/ie7.css'])/>
    <![endif]-->
    <:#meta_tags_ext/>
</head>
<body class="bg">
    <div id="bg_main">
        <div id="main_block" class="gtw">
            <a id="top-of-page"></a>
            <div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
                <:if !#is_admin><:text_include('attach/inc/counters_top.txt')/></:if>
                <:include __SITE__ ~ '/default/header.tpl'/>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="catalog">
                        <a class="arr prev"></a>
                        <a class="arr next"></a>
                        <div class="items">
                            <:menu(1,2,3)/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <:script>
                        $(function(){
                            var btnNext = "#catalog .next",
                                btnPrev = "#catalog .prev",
                                imgCount = $('#catalog .items li.item').length,
                                visible = 5;
                            if (imgCount > 0) {
                                $('#catalog .items').jCarouselLite({
                                    mouseWheel: true,
                                    btnNext: btnNext,
                                    btnPrev: btnPrev,
                                    visible: visible,
                                    auto: 5000,
                                    speed: 800,
                                    circular: true,
                                    scroll: 1
                                });
                            };
                        });
                    </:script>
                    <div class="maintext lcol col_7">
                        <div class="layer">
                            <:if #servicelinks_div>
                                <:lib_load('admin_toolbar')/>
                                <div data-admin-toolbar="wrapChild">
                                    <:#servicelinks_div/>
                                </div>
                                <div data-admin-toolbar="separator" class="hide"></div>
                            </:if>
                            <:content()/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Что за это конструкции? После восстановления сайта на хостинге сыпятся синтаксические ошибки. Что это вообще: `<:if #servicelinks_div>`? И куда копать?

Comment: Очевидно что это это управляющие конструкции для шаблонизатора.  Но что мешает хотя бы посмотреть название cms, чтобы в инете пойти посмотреть потом справку про шаблоны?!

Comment: гугление было, и это судя по всему не какая то распространенная cms , а самопис, по шаблонизатору не смог найти чего то похожего на этот синтаксис, не в конфигах не в каких то других файлах нет никакого описания

Answer (score 1):

ну если это самопал, то никто не сможет вам ничего подсказать...кроме автора этого самопала. Впрочем логически можно предположить (и в браузер тоже можно заглянуть чтобы посмотреть) что во что транслируется .

Логика говорит, что <: это эквивалент <\?php, то есть сигнал шаблонизатору, что тут код, который нужно выполнять.

```
<:if ...</:if>- управляющая инструкция if...endif;
#servicelinks_div это $servicelinks_div
```

А значит

```
<:if #servicelinks_div> транслируется в if($servicelinks_div)
```

А вот это по контексту вывод

```
<:#meta_tags_ext/> это <? echo $meta_tags_ext; ?>
```

Остальное методы

```
<:text_include(
<:menu(1,2,3)
<:include
<content()
```

это прямые намеки на то, что вызываются методы пхп или пользовательские хелперы, которые где то до этого определены и существуют. Причем похоже что сразу идут в вывод.

И остается непонятным только это

```
__SITE__ ~
```